# Can I use getState method from redux store to implement a utility function for my application?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

I have a working react-redux application which does login functionality and redirects users to their respective pages based on their roles. In order to check their roles, I'm using jwt provided by the auth reducer and decoding it in the login component itself (which I think has extractable logic) and redirecting them. I want to do something like this -->

```
//checkAuthAndRole.js -- utility

const {isAuthenticated, token} = store.getState();

function checkAdmin() {
  if(!isAuthenticated) {
return <Redirect to='/login' />
} else //decode token here if role === admin redirect them to admin page
}

// export this utility and call it in respective component
```

Can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Using state in utility would not be a right design. '*isAuthenticated*' and '*token*' can be passed to utility which can then decide the page to load